# Why Zend Framework is adding parentheses in where clause?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have the following query:

```
$tagCordQuery = $this->freqDb->select()
                    ->from("rr_amplifiers", "*")
                    ->join("amplifiers_coordinate", "amplifiers_coordinate.name = TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM  rr_amplifiers.name)", array())
                    ->where("amplifiers_coordinate.name IN(?)", $apsName);
```

Where $apsName it’s an array.

The problem is when this array has only one element the query had extra parenthesis like this:

```
SELECT `rr_amplifiers`.* FROM `rr_amplifiers`
 INNER JOIN `amplifiers_coordinate` ON amplifiers_coordinate.name = TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM  rr_amplifiers.name) WHERE (amplifiers_coordinate.name IN('xpto'))
```

Why this it’s happen?

Comment: Fair question, but note the extra parentheses, in this example, don't matter.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that, but the problem its this parentheses some where, because this error doesn't happen when the array has more than one element

Comment: I think it's not an error, your query can works that way too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in case you did something like this:

```
->where("amplifiers_coordinate.name IN(?) OR something = 1", $apsName);
```

(i.e. include an OR condition in the WHERE). Without the parentheses, the query wouldn't work as you'd expect.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me, the erro its the same:

Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '))' at line 1

Comment: Your question didn't mention a syntax error, and I can't see one in the query you posted. If you cut and paste this query into phpMyAdmin (or your DB tool of choice), does it work?

Comment: You will however get that error if `$apsName` is empty - could that be the issue?

Comment: Okay, ZF wrapping the condition with parentheses was irrelevant there, it's `IN ()` which would cause the syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

Zend Framework allows you to add more than one `where` statement.  Always wrapping the clause in parentheses prevents unintended logic from occuring.